# php socket servers, actionscript 3 and multiplayer

Tags: php, actionscript-3, actionscript, sockets

So I am thinking about creating a multiplayer game and I was wanting to use php because I already have a php server. Is it possible to make a socket server that will be able to handle a actionscript multiplayer game. The game won't be big. so we wont need any huge amount of data pushing through. just some software that is probably reliable enough to run a multiplayer game.

Comment: just use python and save yourself troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is clearly not a solution when it comes to socket server. It's simply not meant for that kind of usage.

If you really want to go multiplayer, SmartFox ( http://www.smartfoxserver.com/) offers a professional solution when it comes to Flash. After that developing a small socket server in a proper language is not that complicated, and the possibility are endless (Python, Java, C#, C, C++, Erlang, Go, Erlang, ...). It really depends on what kind of game you're want to do.

PHP could be eligible as a solution in case of turn by turn type game, you could simply handle it as a RESTful service (sending back and forward the game state by http).

Comment: is there anything possibly free

Comment: http://osflash.org/red5 it's an Open Source implementation of Flash Media Server, i find it to be an overkill for gaming, especially if you not going to complicated. You can look around on google there is some stuff available in Java that give you the base for a good, light and simple game server.

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP, but I wouldn't recommend it. In addition you will need a shell on your server and the ability to execute custom servers, since the PHP socket server will not be running from inside the webserver (Apache etc).

I would recommend one of the many realtime communication servers available for Flash, such as [Wowza](http://www.wowzamedia.com/), [ElectroServer](http://www.electro-server.com/), [Union](http://www.unionplatform.com/), or others (just google for them)

---

There are some free ones available too, but the quality may not be as good. Some examples I found with a 30 second google serach, I know nothing about them: [Oregano](http://www.spicefactory.org/oregano/), [GFS](http://code.google.com/p/gfs-server/), [Palabre](http://palabre.gavroche.net/content/view/18/37/)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Red5. It's an open source Java implementation of a Flash Media Server that allows for what you want to do:
http://osflash.org/red5